# How to select across multiple one to many relationships in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following series of tables

```
Items - contains all items
Purchase_order - 1:m purchased_items
purchased_items - 1:m receipts
receipts - 1:m received_items
recieved_items - 1:m shipments
shipments - 1:m shipped items
```

I need to list out full details of all purchase orders as in purchased_order contains purchased_items, which in turn will have multiple rows of receipts and so on. but all purchase orders might not have receipts, a receipt might not have all of the items of the purchase order e.t.c so I tried to use `LEFT JOIN` starting with `purchase_order` and moving in the above order. Problem is, a `purchase_order` with 6 items will produce 6 duplicate `receipt` which each, in turn, will produce multiple duplicate `received_items` rows and so on...

I know group by won't solve this issue, please point me in the correct direction.

Purchase order:

```
id | name
----------
1  | po1
```

Puchased_items

```
id | purchase_order_id | item_id
--------------------------------
1  | 1                 | 1
2  | 1                 | 4
3  | 1                 | 5
4  | 1                 | 6
```

Receipts

```
id | name | purchase_order_id
------------------------------
1  | rc01 | 1
2  | rc02 | 1
```

Received_items

```
id | receipt_id | item_id
--------------------------------
1  | 1          | 1
2  | 1          | 4
3  | 2          | 5
4  | 2          | 6
```

Shipments

```
id | name | receipt_id
------------------------------
1  | shp01 | 1
2  | shp02 | 1
3  | shp03 | 2
4  | shp04 | 2
```

Shipped_items

```
id | shipment_id | item_id
--------------------------------
1  | 1          | 1
2  | 2          | 4
3  | 3          | 5
4  | 4          | 6
```

Expected output

```
purchase_order_item | purchase_order | receipt | shipment
----------------------------------------------------------
1                   | po1            | rc01    | shp01
2                   | po1            | rc01    | shp02
3                   | po1            | rc02    | shp03
4                   | po1            | rc02    | shp04
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for taking the time to help me, I have added some sample data above

Comment: OK, now just add the expected output, and you should be good to go.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added, please let me know if it's ok